# Spring data JPA expression using deleteBy

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring-data-jpa to perform delete operation.

Currently, I have a query like:

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query("Delete from student s where(:studentName is null Or s.studentName =:studentName) and s.studentId IN(:studentIds)")
int deleteByStudentIdAndRollNo(@Param("studentName") String studentName, @Param("studentIds") List<Integer> studentIds)
```

The above query is working fine and is returning a count of successfully deleted rows from the table.

But the problem is, now I have to return deleted `List<Students>` instead of the number of deleted records.

I am aware of the fact that `@Query` will always return the count of successfully deleted records.

I tried to use **deleteBy** like below:

`List<Student> deleteByStudentIdStudentNameIsNullOrStudentNameIsAndStudentIdIN`
, But that's not working.

Is there any way to get list of deleted students?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article show how to return deleted records: [Spring Data JPA – Derived Delete Methods](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-deleteby)

And try maybe this code:

```
List<Student> deleteAllByStudentNameIsNullOrStudentNameAndStudentIdIn(String studentName, List<Integer> studentIds);
```

But can't be sure that will be work because I don't know your Student's model structure.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Could you please share a reference document, so that I can also learn?

Comment: What document? What do you mean?